# django - specify database for TestCase fixtures

Tags: django, django-testing

I have two databases that my site uses and I have an app that uses both of them. I need to write a TestCase that loads fixtures for both databases. I use a DB router, which works fine in production, but in the testing framework, Django insists on using the 'default' database for all fixtures, even for models that specify the other database. How do I tell Django to run a fixture against another database?

My TestCase is defined list:

```
class VerifierTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['zipcodes_test.json', 'all_states.json', 'wtf.json']
    multi_db = True
```

Comment: Has anybody found an answer for this? Cannot get fixtures to not all load into 'default'

Comment: Has anybody found an answer for this?

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a bug in Django that causes it to ignore the name-based db-specific pointers if you specify the entire fixture name.

so if you do `fixtures = ["mydata.default.yaml", "mydata.myotherdatabase.yaml"]`

It will load both fixtures into the default database.

But if you do `fixtures = ['mydata']`

It will load correctly. This is also true for dbengine specific filenames (e.g. `mydata.default.postgresql.sql`) as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't true with Django 1.6. I get an error stating `UserWarning: No fixture named 'migration_test_data' found` when I try that.

Comment: @CoreDumpError, I also got the warning, but, fixtures were loaded correctly. I think the warnings are kind of bug. I issued a ticket about it: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24680#ticket

Answer (score 2):

Fixtures are targeted at specific databases by filename.  This is true in TestCase instances as well, as they just call the loaddata command.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#database-specific-fixtures

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi-db setup with models exclusive to each database. You need to save a fixture file for each database (with the non-applicable database files being empty).

If your code defines `fixtures = ["sample"]` and you have two databases `default` and `other`.

You need two files: `sample.default.json` and `sample.other.json`. If `sample` contains only models from db `default`, `sample.other.json` will be an empty file (`[]`) and vice-versa.

Tried with **Django 3.2**